# Is there a way to open IOS Settings application from a Flutter button?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I've read multiple articles and answers that were outdated and I wanted to know a more recent opinion on how to solve my issue.
I am Flutter developer, not a Swift one, so I am trying to understand how to connect those two in my application. I've seen that for the swift part the following code should work

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
     }
  }
```

but I don't know how to call the above code only when I click on a specific button from my flutter code and not before opening the app.
I've tried putting this check in a method in the AppDelegate.swift file but didn't seem to work. So, I'll let the code below:

```
public class TestLocalizationPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "test_localization_plugin", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = TestLocalizationPlugin()

     channel.setMethodCallHandler({(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
              switch call.method {
                  case "openSettings":
                    result(UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil))
                  default:
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
              }

          })

    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
     result(UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil))
  }
```

I am aware that something is wrong for sure, since I don't understand completely what the function handle is suppose to do or how the register one works.
If someone could explain me a little bit the process, that would be much appreciated and thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have a look at the [open_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/open_settings) package. Even if it does not directly achieve your goal, a look at its source code may offer some inspiration.

Comment: I don't want to open the settings of my application, just the native application Settings